# How does my neo4j browser still works even when I stop neo4j service?

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j, bolt

```
neo4j.service - Neo4j Graph Database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Mar 06 13:26:43 ip-10-14-12-59 neo4j[12287]: 2020-03-06 13:26:43.564+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.5.14 ========
Mar 06 13:26:43 ip-10-14-12-59 neo4j[12287]: 2020-03-06 13:26:43.572+0000 INFO  Starting...
Mar 06 13:26:49 ip-10-14-12-59 neo4j[12287]: 2020-03-06 13:26:49.780+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
Mar 06 13:26:51 ip-10-14-12-59 neo4j[12287]: 2020-03-06 13:26:51.153+0000 INFO  Started.
Mar 06 13:26:52 ip-10-14-12-59 neo4j[12287]: 2020-03-06 13:26:52.131+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://10.14.12.59:7474/
Mar 06 13:42:38 ip-10-14-12-59 systemd[1]: Stopping Neo4j Graph Database...
Mar 06 13:42:38 ip-10-14-12-59 neo4j[12287]: 2020-03-06 13:42:38.818+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
Mar 06 13:42:38 ip-10-14-12-59 neo4j[12287]: 2020-03-06 13:42:38.832+0000 INFO  Stopping...
Mar 06 13:42:38 ip-10-14-12-59 neo4j[12287]: 2020-03-06 13:42:38.884+0000 INFO  Stopped.
Mar 06 13:42:39 ip-10-14-12-59 systemd[1]: Stopped Neo4j Graph Database.
```

But yet  `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`
Neither 7474 port is listening neither 7687 is listening

Comment: Your question shows that the server is not running and that, as expected, neither port is listening. What is the problem that you are seeing?

Comment: My browser was working even when the services of Neo4j were stopped. @cybersam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your neo4j Browser session is connected to a different (running) neo4j instance (probably on your local host). You can use this Browser command to see the URL it is currently using:

```
:server status
```

You can run these two Browser commands to disconnect, and then connect to the correct instance (the second command will display a form):

```
:server disconnect
:server connect
```

Based on your logs, it looks like you want to set the `Connect URL` to `bolt://10.14.12.59:7687`.